# Perl unable to read in variable to replace words [ksh]

Tags: perl, unix, ksh

I have a text file named 123.txt
In the 123.txt it contains

**is okay %  : That's good**
**not okay % : That's bad**

My job is to replace the word from **"is okay %"** to **okay can %**

My Current Code (Not working)

```
$temp_var="is okay \%"
perl -pi -e 's/$temp_var/okay can \%/g' *123.txt
```

The reason to put a backslash on % to handle special character.

*I have tried using sed -i for my previous coding but it did not work out as -i is not part of the classic interface, i have tried placing **'s/is okay \%/okay can \%/g'** instead of $temp_var and it is able to work.*

I am not too sure if it is the way i cast my variable or $temp_var is not able to read in PERL

Thanks!

Comment: `%` is not a special character in regex literals or in regex patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `s/$temp_var/okay can \%/g`, `$temp_var` refers to a Perl variable. Nothing but that `ksh` process knows about its variables. You will need to provide its value to Perl.

---

Hardcoded:

```
perl -i -pe's/is okay %/okay can %/g' *123.txt
```

Via an argument:

```
text='is okay %'
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN { $text = shift(@ARGV); }
   s/\Q$text/okay can %/g;
' "$text" *123.txt
```

Via an env var:

```
text='is okay %'
TEXT="$text" perl -i -pe's/$ENV{TEXT}/okay can %/g' *123.txt
```

Via an env var:

```
export TEXT='is okay %'
perl -i -pe's/$ENV{TEXT}/okay can %/g' *123.txt
```

---

Note: `"\Q$text\E"` creates a regex that matches the value of `$text`. (A trailing `\E` can be left out.)

Comment: Hello may i know BEGIN { $text = shift(@ARGV); }what does this means?

Comment: At compile-time (i.e. before the loop created by `-p`), grab and remove the first argument.

Comment: How about adding additional **$text2** examepl s/\Q$text $test2/okay can %/g;
' "$text $text2" *123.txt ... Is this violated?

Answer (score 0):

Your substituton works for me, the only thing I did differently is that I also declared the variable $temp_var in the oneliner itself.

```
$ cat so45451136.txt
is okay % : That's good
not okay % : That's bad

$ perl -pe '$temp_var="is okay \%";s/$temp_var/okay can \%/g;' so45451136.txt 
okay can % : That's good
not okay % : That's bad
```

Comment: The OP probably wants to keep using the value of `$temp_var` instead of having the value hardcoded. And if they're ok with having the value hardcoded, why do it in such a complicated manner?

Comment: Hello @ikegami  Because I have to use this mulit-times therefore variable will be a better choice.

Comment: @permanent409  any alternative besides declared in oneliner as the value as actually, it is a function parameter.